# PyCares - Fatal Python error: PyImport_GetModuleDict: no module dictionary

Tags: python, windows

I've been trying to get a script to run on a Windows server. It runs fine on my Mac, but keeps throwing an error at the end of the script. The output from the script is as expected and completes entirely, then this error is thrown:

```
Fatal Python error: PyImport_GetModuleDict: no module dictionary
Current thread 0x00001880 (most recent call first):
    File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pycares\__init__.py", line 387 in (lambda)
```

Currently I'm running Python 3.6.5 and getting this error but I've tried it up to Python 3.7.5 and get the same error. This seems like a Windows specific issue with Pycares since the same script runs fine on my Mac machine. Since the script executes correctly, even on windows, this seems like it is an error thrown in the cleanup of the script.

Any ideas on a cause or a workaround?

Edit: I've found this Python bug https://bugs.python.org/issue26153 that seems to say it's due to a race condition and warnings in the del function, but I still get the issue even when running Python 3.7